# Navigate after clicking checkbox

Tags: checkbox, routes, navigation, checkboxlist

I'm a complete noob when it comes down to coding and Google Forms, but since I'm on a strict deadline I want to ask for your help.

I have two important questions in my Google Form survey which I need to ask via 'Checkboxes'. 
There are 15 checkboxes to choose from. I'm trying to set it up as following:

If someone clicks Checkbox 7 (along with other checkboxes as well) in question 1 that it redirects to question 2. And if someone does not click on checkbox 7 the user gets redirected to question 3.

Is this possible? And how can I accomplish this?

Many thanks in advance!
Pim